# Which is correct: "secret to why" or "secret of why"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it

A) Secret *to* why

or

B) Secret *of* why

Examples:

Discover the secret to why 90% of people...

Discover the secret of why 90% of people...

Comment: I think it's normally *secret to how* and *secret of why*. *Discover the secret to making great hard cider.* *Discover the secret of why the former Prime Minister won't drink coffee.*

Comment: @TimR I doubt you would say: *Discover the secret to how to make great cider.*  Even without the explicit "how", it seems "the secret of making" is more common according to [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+secret+to+making%2Cthe+secret+of+making%2Cthe+secret+to+make%2C&year_start=1800)

Comment: @Henry Indeed, "secret to making" is what I wrote.  With "secret to how" and "secret to why" I was trying to suggest "secret to {method}" and "secret of {some circumstance}", not that those phrases should be prefixed verbatim to some additional words.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where either preposition is probably fine. A [Google N-grams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+secret+of+why%2Cthe+secret+to+why&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests "of" is more common.

Using "to" with "secret" is a bit like:

- the answer **to** the question
- the solution **to** the problem

and so on. All of these involve seeking information, where the question/topic/information-need is named separately from the answer.